# Solve this differential equation using perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Consider the following problem:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}t^2} + y + \epsilon\ y^3 = 0\ \ \ \ \text{for}\ \  t \geq 0, y(0) = A, y'(0)=0$$

Compute an approximate solution by substitution method:

$y(\tau) = y_0(\tau) + \epsilon\ y_1(\tau) + \epsilon^2y_2(\tau) + \ldots$

$\tau = w(\epsilon)t = (1+\epsilon w_1 + \epsilon^2 w_2 + \ldots)t$

$\text{up to the order}\  \epsilon^2$;

I have hard time using such substitution / perturbation method to approximate the exact solution. Any help?

Comment: Put $y(r,\epsilon)$ and $t(\epsilon)$ into the ODE. Expend to power series of $\epsilon$. Identify so that the coefficients be nul. Information ouitside the scope of the question : The exact solution (without approximation) can be expressed thanks to the Jacobi elliptic functions.

Comment: can you show me? I don't get it...

Comment: Write yourself what you have done (in addition to your question). So that one could verify if there is no mistake.

Comment: You shouldn't need to scale $t$ here, just $y$.

Comment: Yep, exact duplicate, well found!!

Comment: cf. this article on the [Poincaré-Lindstedt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Lindstedt_method) perturbation method.

Answer (score 1):

Set $y(t)=r(t)\cos(w(t))$ and $\dot y(t)=-r(t)\sin(w(t))$. Then compute
$$
\dot r=\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{y^2+\dot y^2}
$$
and 
$$
\dot w=-\frac{d}{dt}\arctan \frac{\dot y}{y}
$$
and insert the differential equation to remove second order derivatives and then the zero-order solutions to obtain the first order approximations.

---

Another approach is to observe that the system is conservative with first integral
$$
E(\dot y, y)=\dot y^2+y^2+\fracϵ2y^4, \quad E(0,a)=a^2+\fracϵ2a^4
$$
so that the solutions are periodic and symmetric. One quarter of the period length $2\pi w(ϵ)$ can be obtained by integrating
$$
w(ϵ)\frac\pi2=\int_0^a\frac1{\sqrt{(a^2-y^2)(1+\fracϵ2(a^2+y^2))}}dy
\\=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{ϵa^2}2(1+\sin^2u)}}du
$$